# sign token key SPI keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I am using keycloak for token administration for users.

For requirements i need save the sign key in a secure vault that we have

At this moment keycloak save the sign private key in database:

```
 SELECT VALUE, CC.NAME FROM COMPONENT_CONFIG CC
 INNER JOIN COMPONENT C INNER JOIN REALM R ON(CC.COMPONENT_ID = C.ID AND R.ID = C.REALM_ID)
 WHERE R.NAME='test' AND CC.name = 'privateKey';
```

Is possible create a SPI to get the key from other location, for dummy example, is possible create a SPI for use a key hardcoded in a string variable to avoid save the private key in database?

I am using a container Docker with version 21.1.0 (Quarkus version)